# Android read Text from a website

Tags: android, string, url

I'm pretty new to Android programming, however I'm used to program for iOS though...

Now in iOS you have the function of NSString stringWithContentOfURL. Now my Question is, if there is a similar option in java as well...? While searching in google i've come through some examples, but using them my app always crashes...

I used codes like this: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/17/how-to-read-webpage-contents-as-a-string-in-android/ but it keeps crashing... Could you please help me?

Thank you!

Edit: 
LogCat Errors:

```
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.example.test4.DieActivity.meldeAn(DieActivity.java:150)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.example.test4.DieActivity$1.onClick(DieActivity.java:56)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-22 19:34:12.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Showing the Logcat error would be helpful. But a stab in the dark, have you declared internet permissions in your Manifest file?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Yes, it is declared and my Errors an in the Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have tried to perform (network) IO on the UI thread. this is not allowed. why? because if you hang the UI thread, the system will post an ANR (activity not responding) dialog to the user..

you must perform IO asynchronously,

```
new AysyncTask<String,Void,String>() {
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
              String url = urls[0];
              // do network operation, get result in a string (for example)
              return resultString;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
              // update UI with the results of the network call here
            }
        }.execute(aUrl);
```

this is especially important for network IO, but it follows for disk IO as well. take a look at [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for details. the interface for `AsyncTask` is a little obtuse IMHO.

there's nothing special about `AsyncTask`, it's wraps a pattern around creating a thread and updating the user interface based on the results. in the old days, we used to do it like this,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // do network operation
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // update UI thread here
      }
    });
  }
}}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Android is telling you that you shouldn't be doing network operations on the UI thread. It doesn't want you to block the thread, and for good reasons.

Try using an `AsyncTask` instead. Put your HTTP request code in the `doInBackground()` method and update the `TextView` in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Keep in mind that you **CANNOT** access the UI thread from the `doInBackground()` method.